# Converting binary characters to something jQuery can use

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I’m using the [BinaryWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx) method of the HttpResponse class to fetch a web page.

Something similar to the example…

```
FileStream MyFileStream;
long FileSize;

MyFileStream = new FileStream("APage.html", FileMode.Open);
FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;

byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
MyFileStream.Close();

Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
```

I’m then using the jQuery ajax method to get that response. But I’m having trouble doing anything with it - so if I had…

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "GetUrl.Proxy",
    data: { url: 'http://www.example.org/test.html' },
    success: function(data) {
        $('iframe').contents().find('html body').html(data.toString());
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
    }
 });
```

This returns a stream of binary characters, what I want is something that jQuery can use to set a html element.

Comment: Well, *all* content is just a stream of "binary characters".  What's going wrong, exactly?  What is in the response?  What's the MIME type being sent by the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the content-type first:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
...
```

In response to the question of finding the content type of the file:

```
string mt = "application/unknown";
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();
var regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
if (regKey != null) {
  var tempMt = regKey.GetValue("Content Type");
  if (tempMt != null) {
    tempMt = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
  }
}
```

Personally, I'd probably just do a switch statement with the likely extensions and types...

Comment: Oops, embarrassing simple. Can you think of a way to find out the content type from the file stream… if this example where expanded and a Url parameter was used together with WebClient()

Comment: AFAIK you have to have registry access to do it, so this wouldn't work in most shared hosting environments, but check-out my edit above.

Comment: You might need the registry to do it properly but as a security measure its best to explicitly decide which files you want served up this way (for example to prevent them getting the DLLs for your site and looking for exploits) so having a switch statement and then if tis not in that allowed list then throw a 404 or similar.